# Why can't Stack Overflow update automatically

Tags: support, global-inbox

Why do I need to refresh Stack Overflow in order to see new messages, answers, etc.? Why can't it just update automatically? And why when I press the "go back" button in my browser (and it switches from one Stack Overflow page to the previous one) I see my previous status (before the new messages/answers/reputation changes) and not my updated status? When you are expecting an answer, it is very annoying to refresh every 30 seconds or so. Can it be changed?

Comment: Sounds like your network provider is blocking websocket requests?  I don't know if it falls back to long-polling anymore.

Comment: You should be getting live updates to the top bar such as rep changes and notifications for new answers/comments. If you're not, you may have an issue with your browser or an addon or something higher up the chain. As for why going back in time shows you stuff from the past, why wouldn't it?

Comment: I consider it a feature, sometimes I'm reading a post that gets deleted and the post gets greyed out before I finish, so I click a link, then hit the back button on my browser, and the deleted post is there and not getting removed automatically. But that's just me.

Comment: @DavyM just get to 10K you  lazy .. wait ... be nice ...  ;)

Comment: Happens to me also in Chrome but not Firefox so I surf site in Firefox. Annoying in Chrome

Comment: @charlietfl thanks! I'm a chrome user so it must be it. I will surf StackOverflow from firefox from now on.

Comment: Stack Overflow has supported live refresh for [7 years now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox), so something is wrong on your side if it doesn't work for you. See [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161) on the main Meta site for what requirements you need to meet for the live refresh feature to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like George Stocker said, your websocket requests maybe aren't working correctly.

But, it should be automatic. Your "recent inbox messages" and "recent achievements" at the top right should give you updates automatically. If it doesn't, click it 2 times and it will update.

Comment: You might use this service http://websocketstest.com/ to see if the browser and network allow proper operation of websockets.